# ConnectionRequest Response Code when the internet connectivity is lost

Tags: codenameone

I have a question, I would like to know whether ConectionRequest returns response code is 502 or 0 when internet connection lost during the query on Mobile device. Testing Tool returns 502 when there is no internet and debugging the code in Simulator returns response code 0. I would like to know what would be the response code when there is no connectivity during network call. Please advise.

Also, is there a better method to detect offline mode during the network call. I'm aware of Connectivity lib already.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will behave in an inconsistent way because the underlying platforms behave very differently. You need to test for positive responses e.g. server returned 200 instead of testing for negative outcome such as error codes.

You should get an error response callback but we can't guarantee it.

Comment: In that case, how would I distinguish between bad response and internet lost during the call. I have to do different action based on bad response and connectivity lost. Offline method will test before the network but not during the network call. Please advise.

Comment: A bad response would return an error code you would be familiar with and the content from the server would be a recognizable structure you can parse.